# Different *.csproj / *.config settings for each team member and branch

Tags: c#, .net, version-control, visual-studio-2012, csproj

This question is kind-of two in one, but both are related to the same problem.

We are a team of 10 developers, some developers prefer to use a full instance of IIS, while others prefer to use IIS-Express.  There are merits to using either, for example, IIS most closely resembles production, while IIS-Express allows Edit-and-Continue debugging.

In addition to the 10 developer work team, we are using source control, and we have a branching structure.  Each branch may have different web.config / app.config settings, such as database connection strings.  A developer may be working on more than one branch a time, so we typically have one database per branch, we are looking at developers having local databases, but the naming collision is still a problem regardless of the approach (i.e. a developer may have 2 local databases, one for each branch).

The first issue, is the one with the csproj files, specifically the web-server settings.  If one developer checks in a csproj file that uses IIS-Express, and the other developer does a *Get Latest*, it will overwrite their configuration, wasting time and creating frustration.

Of course, the easiest solution would be to force everyone to use one tool, one configuration, but I would rather not do that, especially for something that has no bearing on the resulting output (compiled code).

The second issue is with the config files, the config files are stored in source control (just like any other file), so when we do branching-merging, these files have to be updated manually afterwards.  I know that there are the Debug and Release transformations for config files, which we could have different connection strings in both, but this does not solve the issue for two individual developers may be working on the same branch but with different connection strings.

The obvious solution to this is everyone has the exact same settings always, but some developers may want to use LocalDB instance, others may want to use SQL-Express, while the staging server uses a full-on SQLServer Instance.  Again, this is another setting that has no bearing one the final result.

I have not seen any solutions to my particular problems, in regards to managing configurations between team members, and between branching/merging.

Comment: I tend to lean toward forcing people to have the same environment. The subtle differences between web servers or database versions can mean the difference between a feature working or not in production (the dreaded "works on my machine" syndrome). IIS (or IIS Express) vs Cassini is a big one there. But if you avoid any patterns that could potentially be a problem, I suppose you'd probably be ok.

Comment: I agree this would be a solid approach to have everyone use the same thing, if we could get everyone to agree what that should be.  Unfortunately I am not in a position to tell others how to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specifically for web server, VS has a checkbox of "Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)" - if unchecked, then the setting is stored in your local .csproj.user file, so everyone can have their own settings there.

For connection strings, you can have a "user.config" file on each machine (not in source control), where the developer can put their connection string in. The main config file can just load this file up to get the connection string. There are a few ways of doing this, but I've tried this:

```
App.config or Web.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="user.config"></connectionStrings>
</configuration>

user.config:
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="test" connectionString="Server=.;Database=...;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

If it was a Windows app, you'd set the "Copy to Output Directory" property on the user.config file, so that Visual Studio would copy it to your bin directory.

Comment: Thanks for this, I never noticed the "Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)" checkbox.  I think I can hack around the user.config file suggestion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you would basically like to exclude your app.config / web.config / certain other files from being checked in?  For some reason, this seems to be somewhat of a hidden option...

We finally found the answer to our similar problem by selecting the .config files in the Solution Explorer, and clicking on (Visual Studio) `File` -> `Source Control` -> `Exclude selection from Source Control`.

This will keep the selected files from being checked in and overwriting the other developer's files.

(Note: this works in VS2010, I can't make any guarantee that this option exists in 2012)

Comment: Sort of, our web.config files are gigantic.  the only things that change regularly is the connection strings, plus a few other settings.  The problem if I exclude these from source control, if someone adds a new web.config setting or section, that change is not propagated to anyone else, and everyone has to update their configs if they start working on that branch.

Comment: Why not put all variable web.config content in separate files which get referenced in the main web.config, and keep those files only locally - not checked in.

Comment: @Matthew true, it's not a perfect solution, but for us, it's gotten rid of a huge headache... the separate .config files may well be a better solution for you, I just thought I'd pitch in my two cents on the solution we are using... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem where I have had 3 databases for 3 branches for 3 environments.

Production Server ==> Production DB ==> prod branch ==> Prod connection string
Testing Server ==> Master DB ==> Master branch ==> master connection string
local Development  ==> local DB ==> developer branch ==> developer connection string ...

Inside of .git folder, there are git hooks where you can put scripts to execute whenever you checkout a branch. I have post-checkout script which executes itself every time I checkout and that updates connection string for me so that saves me from manual changes to the web.config file :

## !/bin/bash

. config
eval $(git branch | grep "*" | sed "s/* //")

sed -e s/{SERVER}/$server/g -e s/{DATABASE}/$database/g -e s/{USER}/$user/g -e s/{PASS}/$pass/g  -e s/{SITE_TYPE}/$site_type/g \